# Why does re.sub match \ when r-string (r'\\..') is used in re.sub criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
txt=r"\\xa3100.00."
print(txt)
```

Output: `\\xa3100.00.`

```
txt="\\xa3100.00."
print(txt)
```

Output: `\xa3100.00.`

In the following example, the txt value has got `\\` which effectively is `\` because `\` is an escape character when used without r-string.

So why does re.sub substitute the `\\` when I have used r-string in the re.sub search criteria (r-string means there is `\\` and not `\` in the value)? Why does re.sub match \ when r-string (r'\..') is used in re.sub criteria?

```
txt="\\xa3100.00."
import re
re.sub(r"\\xa3", r"£", txt)
```

Output: `£100.00.`

Comment: what is your expected output and what is the output you are getting with your code

Comment: Why does re.sub substitute the \\ when I have used r-string (which means there is \ and not \\ in the value)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because `\` also has a special meaning in regular expressions, and it means "consider next character 'as is' even if it would be special for the regular expression syntax".

You pattern indeed begins with

```
 \\xa3
```

but that means

- a literal `\`
- `x`
- `a`
- `3`

In other words `r"\\xa3"` means a string with content `\\xa3`, while `"\\xa3"` means a string with content `\xa3`; however the string content `\\xa3` for a regular expression means the PATTERN `\xa3`.

The backslash `\` is used as an escape BOTH for the quoted string and for the regular expression.

You need to use `r"\\\\xa3"` for example.

Comment: But I have used r-string as shown in my code example. So why does re.sub match \ when r-string (r'\\..') is used in re.sub criteria?

Comment: It's because of how regular expressions work. `"\\xa3100".replace(r"\\xa3", "£")` will not match, as you would expect. But the first argument of `re.sub` is not treated as a string, it is treated as a regular expression. And in regular expressions, the literal string ``\\`` matches a single backslash.